# Как в данном случае идет вызов метода?

Tags: java

Помогите разобраться в работе данного кода
`sb.append(agent.toYamlTestCase());`

Ссылка на полный документ https://github.com/nielsbasjes/yauaa/blob/master/analyzer/src/main/java/nl/basjes/parse/useragent/debug/AbstractUserAgentAnalyzerTester.java (строка 281)

Вопрос возник из-за того, что `agent` - это `DebugUserAgent` и внутри него нет метода `toYamlTestCase()`, но в коде идет вызов данного метода, как такое может быть?

Для справки `toYamlTestCase()` находится в совершенно другом классе (UserAgent)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Смотрим внимательно на сигнатуру класса

```java
DebugUserAgent extends MutableUserAgent implements UserAgent has default toYamlTestCase
```

`DebugUserAgent` реализует интерфейс `UserAgent` и наследуется от `MutableUserAgent`

Из этого следует, что реализация `toYamlTestCase` лежит либо в одном, либо в другом, либо в его предках.

Java это объектно-ориентированный язык и наследование является одним из основных свойств ООП.

Начиная с Java 8 в интерфейсах можно указывать реализацию метода по умолчанию.
Соответственно если в таком интерфейсе указан метод с реализацией по умолчанию, то его необязательно реализовывать в вашем классе.

И если внимательнее присмотреться к сигнатуре то можно увидеть

```java
implements UserAgent has default toYamlTestCase
```

Что можно прочитать как "реализует интерфейс UserAgent с реализацийе по умолчанию toYamlTestCase"

И если мы перейдем на исходник данного интерфейса - мы можем найти этот метод.

```java
default String toYamlTestCase() {
    return toYamlTestCase(false, null);
}
```

Это и есть искомая реализация.

Ссылка на реализацию toYamlTestCase внутри интерфейса UserAgent:
https://github.com/nielsbasjes/yauaa/blob/59757e9ef86465c7f02aa344db4bfc132d4fe4dd/analyzer/src/main/java/nl/basjes/parse/useragent/UserAgent.java#L240

Comment: Вот кстати интересно, откуда взялась эта строка "DebugUserAgent extends MutableUserAgent implements UserAgent has default toYamlTestCase" - сигнатура класса `DebugUserAgent` выглядит просто как `public class DebugUserAgent extends MutableUserAgent`: https://github.com/nielsbasjes/yauaa/blob/master/analyzer/src/main/java/nl/basjes/parse/useragent/debug/DebugUserAgent.java#L35

Comment: @insolor, спасибо за замечание. Это именно та самая строка, которую отказался комментировать и объяснять Игорь. Стоит отметить что он не просто скопировал сигнатуру, а дополнил её, чтобы из нее было чуть лучше видно что произошло с методом. Хотя это не сильно поможет человеку, который не очень то и знаком с концепцией наследования. А я настолько спешил помочь, что забыл проверить. Еще раз спасибо за замечание - сегодня исправлю ответ.